# javascript array query

Tags: javascript, arrays

am trying to loop and get the values of names from this array , but am not able..really frustrated with javascript

can anyone please help and guide me to do this and for more complex arrays.. i cant seem to find and tutorial good to show examples of this

thank you , here is the code

```
    var object={name:'angelos',name:'nick',name:'maria'};
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < object.length; i += 1) {
        document.writeln(object[name][i]);
    }
```

Comment: your array is set up wrong.  To do what you want you should have 
var object =[{name:'angelos'},{name:'nick'},{name:'maria'}] and then can iterate over object[i]['name']

Comment: AFAIS there is only one property name: 'maria' on your object. THe last one overrules all previous values on name. var object={name:'angelos',name:'nick',name:'maria'}; is equivalent to var object={name:'maria'};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your object has duplicate keys `name`. This is poor code and will throw an error in strict mode.

I would also use either a `for ... in` loop or `Array.forEach` here, because much less code is required to implement the desired effect.

Seems like you need to use an Array:

```
var arr = ["nick", "maria", "chaz"];

arr.forEach(function (name) {
    document.writeln(name);
});
```

You can use `Array.forEach`, which passes in each index to an anonymous function.

**Alternatively**, if you wanted each person to be an `Object`:

```
var people = [{name: 'chaz', title: 'mr'}, {name: 'nick', title: 'mr'}, {name: 'maria',title: 'ms'}];

for (i in people) {
    if (!people.hasOwnProperty(i)) { continue; }

    var person = people[i];
    document.writeln(person.name);
}
```

**References**

- Take a look at [`Array.forEach` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- A good reference on [`for ... in` loops here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: Be aware that this is ECMAScript 5 syntax, and so is unsupported in quite a few current browsers.

Comment: Updated, and `Array.forEach` is easily implemented. Alternatively, in its place, a `for...in` loop can be used.

Comment: What specifically is not working? Do you have a console log or updated code?

Comment: am only getting the last value of the array which is maria

Comment: With the exact code i posted, should work fine. Try using `console.log` in place of `document.writeLn` and look in your console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14748/discussion-between-user1526175-and-austin)

Comment: For those interested, [here](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html) is a _very_ good explanation on the differences between Object and Array

Answer (score 6):

That's an object, not an array. You can make it a simple array instead:

```
var arr = ['angelos', 'nick', 'maria'];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(arr[i]);
}
```

Or, if you want to have objects inside the array (not needed if every object has just one key):

```
var arr = [{name: 'angelos'}, {name: 'nick'}, {name: 'maria'}];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(arr[i].name);
}
```

Comment: It's also not a *legal* object, so your changes wouldn't be enough to fix this. It's not legal to have a literal object that has duplicate property names.

Comment: @Chris I edited that out seconds after I posted my answer (more than 5 minutes ago). Please refresh the page.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, that is an object, not an array. You probably meant to have an array of objects. I'm saying that because you have three keys all called `name`. Keys must be unique. like this:

```
var people = [{name: 'angelos'}, {name:'nick'}, {name:'maria'}];
```

In that case you would loop through like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    document.writeln(people[i].name);
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lbstr/cMqaH/

Comment: am only getting the last value of the array which is maria

Comment: @user1526175 hmm, I'm getting all three. Try the jsfiddle I added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your data in an array and fill it with objects containing a name attribute (and others e.g. adress or so, if you like to)

http://jsfiddle.net/5NK6x/

```
var obj=[{name:'angelos'}, {name:'nick'}, {name:'maria'}],
    i;
for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i += 1) {
    document.write(' ' + obj[i]['name']);
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a mix between an array and JSON.  If your data looked like this:

```
var object = [{"name":"angelos"},{"name":"nick"},{"name":"maria"}];
```

You'd be able to access the elements like so:

```
for(var i=0,i<object.length,i++)
{
    alert(object[i].name);
 }
```